# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]:

Tags: objective-c, iphone, arrays, dictionary, plist

Hello I'm a little doubt in my code.
I am recovering data object classes to insert a collection view, first managed successfully.
But in the second unsuccessful.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


CustomerCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

ButtonSettings * button = [[CVDataController sharedInstance].LBData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.nameServicosButton setTitle:button.Title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

if ([[CVDataController sharedInstance].listData count] > 0) {
    [cell.nameServicosButton addTarget:self action:@selector(novajanela) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    NSLog(@"Maior");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Menor");
}

cell.customerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:button.Image];

return cell;
}
```

This is the first ViewController this way is working and getting properly.

[Esta é a minha estrutura do Plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Csae.png)

I need to retrieve the information in this Array called Button Settings which is within the Dicionario.

My class who controls the data.

```
- (instancetype)initWithDataPList {

self = [super init];

if (self) {
    NSMutableArray * lb = [PlistManager loadMutableArrayFromPlist:@"ListadeEspera" location:@"doc"];
    if (lb.count>0) {

        NSMutableArray * leaderBoardList = [NSMutableArray new];

        for (NSMutableDictionary * dicPlayer in lb) {

            ButtonSettings * player = [[ButtonSettings alloc] initWithDictionary:dicPlayer];

            [leaderBoardList addObject:player];
        }
        _LBData = [leaderBoardList mutableCopy];
    }
    if (_LBData.count>0) {

        NSMutableArray * leaderBoardList = [NSMutableArray new];

        for (ButtonSettings * buttom in _LBData) {

            NSMutableDictionary * dicPlayer = [NSMutableDictionary new];
            [dicPlayer setValue:buttom.buttonData forKey:@"ButtoSettings"];

            [leaderBoardList addObject:dicPlayer];
        }
        _listData = [leaderBoardList mutableCopy];

    }
}
return self;
}
```

You need a way to load the listData with the information only from ButtonSettings if I put a NSLog this listData will display only the information related to ButtonSettings due to filter put, but in time to launch this code excerpt showing an error.

this is the code view of the second controller

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


CustomerCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


ButtonSettings * button = [[ButtonSettings alloc] init];
button.buttonData = [[CVDataController sharedInstance].listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSMutableDictionary * dicData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSString * titleData = [dicData objectForKey:@"Title"];
NSLog(@"%@",titleData);

[cell.nameServicosButton setTitle:button.Title forState:UIControlStateNormal];


if ([[CVDataController sharedInstance].listData count] > 0) {
    [cell.nameServicosButton addTarget:self action:@selector(novajanela) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}else{
    NSLog(@"Menor");
}

cell.customerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:button.Image];

return cell;
}
```

I've tried in the same way the first ViewController but in error.

Comment: Yeah lots of code.  JSON involved by any chance?

Comment: The error message `[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]:` means that the receiver of the `objectAtIndex` message is a dictionary instead of the expected array

Comment: Okay, how can I fix this error? Thanks, for comment.